# How to average the two images, feed them as input to a network and output the two separate images that were used in the average input?

Tags: image-processing, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network, encoder-decoder, image-generation

Given a pair of images from CIFAR10, average the two images, feed them as input to a network and output the two separate images that were used in the average input.

I am currently using conditional GAN and autoencoders to achieve this task. But have not achieved the desired results till now, the model is being trained but I wanted to know if this is the right direction to solve this task...

This is the output that I am getting till now...

[image]

Comment: Could  you find the best model for this?

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid if this problem can be solved. What are you getting at the output?

Comment: added to the question